# how to properly "extend" a docker compose service from another project

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Let's say I have two independent/standalone docker compose projects?
At some point I realized that I also need a service from the other project
the first project looks like this:

```yaml
// ./module_a/docker/docker-compose.yml
version: "3"
name: "module_a"

networks:
  module_a-network:
    driver: bridge
    external: false
services:
  module_a:
    platform: linux/amd64
    image: hello-world:latest
    networks:
      - module_a-network
  module_b:
    extends:
      file: ../module_b/docker/docker-compose.yaml
      service: module_b
    networks:
      - module_a-network
```

The second file looks like this:

```yaml
// ./module_b/docker/docker-compose.yml
version: "3"
name: "module_b"

networks:
  module_b-network:
    driver: bridge
    external: false
services:
  module_b:
    platform: linux/amd64
    image: hello-world:latest
    networks:
      - module_b-network
```

when I start module_a, I get this error:

```
service "module_b" refers to undefined network module_b-network: invalid compose project
```

I can't see what I am doing wrong, any help would be really appreciated! :-)

I tried to add - module_a-network to the module_b service but I got a similar erro in module_b

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to add network b to module a like this:

```
version: "3"
name: "module_a"

networks:
  module_a-network:
    driver: bridge
    external: false
  module_b-network:
    driver: bridge
    external: false
services:
  module_a:
    platform: linux/amd64
    image: hello-world:latest
    networks:
      - module_a-network
  module_b:
    extends:
      file: ../module_b/docker-compose.yml
      service: module_b
    networks:
      - module_a-network
```

Comment: Thanks @Wiicolas this works!!!!! :-) the only thing that it makes me feel uneasy is that I have to create a network that I won't use :-(

Answer (score 2):

Compose automatically creates a network named `default` for you.  Each separate Compose project has its own `default` network, which is basically configured exactly the way you show the manual network configuration.  Also see [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) in the Docker documentation for more details on this.

This means you can safely delete *all* of the `networks:` blocks in both files.  The containers will be automatically set to `networks: [default]`.  Now since the `default` network exists in the file you're importing into (as a different per-project `default` network, but that shouldn't matter) you won't have this conflict.

So for example you can trim down the imported project to

```yaml
# ./module_b/docker/docker-compose.yml
version: "4.x"
name: "module_b"  # NB: not supported in Compose file version 3
services:
  module_b:
    platform: linux/amd64
    image: hello-world:latest
# NB: no networks: anywhere in this file
```

then you should be able to import the file into the other project

```yaml
# ./module_a/docker/docker-compose.yml
version: "4.x"
name: "module_a"
services:
  module_a:
    platform: linux/amd64
    image: hello-world:latest
  module_b:
    extends:
      file: ../module_b/docker/docker-compose.yaml
      service: module_b
```

(Also consider moving these Compose files out of directories named `docker`.  Compose uses the innermost directory name as its default project name, so if you have two projects that both have Compose files in `docker` directories, Compose will think they are "the same".  But a `module_a/docker-compose.yml` will be distinct from a `module_b/docker-compose.yml`.  That will also let you get rid of the `name:` directive, and you can use the Compose file version 3 format if for some reason you still need the older Python-based Compose implementation.)